# How to select a random word from a txt file?

Tags: java, file

I have a method that needs to select a random word from a txt file, but it only works some of the time.

The content of the file is as follows:

```
Broccoli
Tomato
Kiwi
Kale
Tomatillo
```

My code:

```java
import java.util.Random; 
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.io.FileInputStream; 
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public String getRandomItem(){
    Scanner fileIn = null;

    String temp = ""; 
    int r = randomGenerator.nextInt(5) + 1; 
    byte i = 0;

    try {
        fileIn = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("bundles.txt"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found.");
        System.exit(0);
    } 

    while(i <= 5){
        temp = fileIn.nextLine();

        if(i == r){ 
            break;  
        }

        i++;
    }

    fileIn.close();

    return temp; 
}
```

Could someone please tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: Run this in a debugger and see for yourself why it's not always working.

Comment: How do you know that it is random only some of the times? Run in at least 1000x times and analyze the result to see the actual randomness.

Comment: I don't mean it's not always random, I mean I get an error message: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found

Comment: You're generating a random number between 1 and 5 but your index "i" goes from 0 - 5

Comment: I think you are suffering from an off-by-one error. If the random number is 5. You will read 6 lines from the file, thus your error. Change `i<=5` to `i<5`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [`Files.readAllLines(Path)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-) to read all the lines once, and then get a single random word from that. Something like,

```
private static List<String> lines = null;
static {
    try {
        lines = Files.readAllLines(new File("bundles.txt").toPath());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
private Random rand = new Random();

public String getRandomItem() {
    return lines.get(rand.nextInt(lines.size()));
}
```